# Change AFI in RFID with NFC

Tags: nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I can't find information about if it's possible change AFI number in RFID chip with NFC. I'm sure it's possible read AFI number with NFC. AFI number has some special block on RFID chip thats reason why I'm not sure if it's possible change it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a ISO 15693 tag you can use the NfcV command **transceive(byte[] data)** to send a "**write AFI**" command to the tag, followed by a "**Lock AFI**" command to lock the AFI value.

**Write AFI** has the command code 0x27. **Lock AFI** has the command code 0x28.

This should work as long as the RFID chip supports AFI (AFI is optional) and the AFI of that tag has not been programmed beforehand.

You can find more details about AFI in the **ISO 15693-3**.

See: [See Android reference for transceive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcV.html#transceive%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Please, do you know how I can unlock AFI ?

Comment: ISO15693-3 states in chapter 9.3.9 Lock AFI: "When receiving the Lock AFI request, the VICC shall lock the AFI value permanently into its memory." The keyword here is permanently. There is also no unlock command.

So, once you have locked the AFI, there is no way back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this post about the application family identifier : [google](https://my.st.com/public/Faq/Lists/faqlst/DispForm.aspx?ID=183&level=2&objectid=1280&type=product&Source=/public/FAQ/Tags.aspx?tags=rf-id)

> In ISO 15693, the AFI describes the type of application targeted by the reader. This identifier is used to extract all transponders in the reader field that meet the required application criteria. After the reader sends out the AFI, only the AFI-compliant transponders of the appropriate family will respond. Programmed by the transponder issuer, the **AFI is read-only** and its value cannot be modified.

However I see some systems seem to allow you to write the AFI code, and sa well as lock it. I guess it may be up the individual the chip manufacturer. So while its not locked, I guess you could change it. Who makes your the card you are trying to write to?

Comment: It would same risky not to lock these cards, as changing the AFI code might stop the readers from detecting or reading the cards. What is the problem you have?

Comment: We are able change AFI number with RFID reader and PC program we made. My problem is I cant find informations if its possible change AFI number without RFID reader but using technology NFC. Im trying find out if technology NFC is able change AFI value.